# Appcelerator Alloy - application get restarted after 5-10 min

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am developing an app using appcelerator alloy.
But after 5-10 min getting following logs in Titanium Studio and application get restarted

```
[INFO] :   TiAnalyticsSvc: (Thread-13330) [30380,30380] Analytics Service Started
[INFO] :   TiAnalyticsSvc: (Thread-13330) [10537,40917] Stopping Analytics Service
[INFO] :   libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000000c (code=1), thread 19628 (KrollRuntimeThr)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to change the `<analytics>false</analytics>` in `tiapp.xml`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug , I could write a long story about this but the best thing is to follow this link to the appcelerator forums : https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/153444/app-crashes-occasionally-with-fatal-signal-11-on-android.

Also check your memory usage. If you parse a JSON feed into a tableview for example , and forget to give the tableViewRows a class, memory consumption tends to go trough the roof.